# Layer error when changing platforms

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, landsat, sentinel-2

I am running an analysis of vegetation and fire over a 20 year period.
From 2020 - 2016, I have been using the Sentinel-2 imagery but from 2015 back to 1998 I need to use Landsat imagery.
The bands being used for the Sentinel imagery are: ['B12', 'B11', 'B8A','B8', 'B4', 'B3', 'B2'], for Landsat: ['SR_B7', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'].
All seems to go well until I try to set visualisation parameters and display the data.  The Sentinel code below works fine:

```
//  SET VISUALISATION PARAMETERS AND DISPLAY ON MAP
var visNDWI = {palette:['grey','green','blue'],min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['nd']};
var vis = {palette:['white','black'],min: -12000, max: 2000, bands: ['B12_1']};
var rgb_vis = {min: 0, max: 3000, bands: ['B12', 'B8', 'B3']}; // <---  *** CHANGE BANDS FOR RGB VISUALISATION ***
var rgb_vis2 = {min: -2000, max: 3000, bands: ['B12_1', 'B8A', 'B4']};
var filtMosaic = T1ndwi.mosaic();
var filtMosaicT2 = T2ndwi.mosaic();
Map.addLayer(filtMosaic.clip(roi), visNDWI, 'NDWI',false);
Map.addLayer(filtMosaicT2.clip(roi), visNDWI, 'NDWI T2',false);
Map.addLayer(filtMosaic, rgb_vis, 'RGB',false);
Map.addLayer(filtMosaicT2, rgb_vis, 'RGB T2',false);
```

However, when I modify it for Landsat imagery:

```
//  SET VISUALISATION PARAMETERS AND DISPLAY ON MAP
var visNDWI = {palette:['grey','green','blue'],min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['nd']};
var vis = {palette:['white','black'],min: -12000, max: 20000, bands: ['SR_B7_1']};
var rgb_vis = {min: 0, max: 20000, bands: ['SR_B7', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B3']}; // <---  *** CHANGE BANDS FOR RGB VISUALISATION ***
var rgb_vis2 = {min: -2000, max: 20000, bands: ['SR_B7_1', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B4']};
var filtMosaic = T1ndwi.mosaic();
var filtMosaicT2 = T2ndwi.mosaic();
Map.addLayer(filtMosaic.clip(darwin), visNDWI, 'NDWI',false);
Map.addLayer(filtMosaicT2.clip(darwin), visNDWI, 'NDWI T2',false);
Map.addLayer(filtMosaic, rgb_vis, 'RGB',false);
Map.addLayer(filtMosaicT2, rgb_vis, 'RGB T2',false);
```

I get an error message of:

```
Layer error: ImageCollection.mosaic: Error in map(ID=LC08_106069_20150511):
Image.select: Pattern 'SR_B7_1' did not match any bands.
```

I don't understand why using 'B12_1' doesn't give an error but using 'SR_B7_1' does.
I am relatively new to coding and Google Earth Engine so I'm hoping this is a simple error with a simple solution.

Comment: Use `bandNames()` to check the band names of the Landsat image. Sounds like 'SR_B7_1' do not match any of the available band names.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I understand what you are saying, but the band 'B12_1' technically doesn't exist either, yet the sentinel code works.  I'm sure it is something fairly simple, I just can't see it.